# Missing sorting when changed page in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I need to sort a column in a **GridView** and this worked but I've problem when I change pages in **GridView** because missing the sorting, can you help me?

Below is my code **C#** for sorting column in **GridView**, thanks in advance.

```
public SortDirection dir
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["dirState"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["dirState"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
        }
        return (SortDirection)ViewState["dirState"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["dirState"] = value;
    }
}

protected void gridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    sortingDirection = string.Empty;
    if (dir == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Descending;
        sortingDirection = "Desc";
    }
    else
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Ascending;
        sortingDirection = "Asc";
    }

    DataView sortedView = new DataView(GridViewBind());
    sortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + sortingDirection;
    PleaseWait();
    GridView1.DataSource = sortedView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}


public DataTable GridViewBind()
{

sql1 = " SELECT * FROM `tbl` ORDER BY empid DESC; ";

dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql1, myConnectionString);
dset = new DataSet();
dset.Clear();
dadapter.Fill(dset);
DataTable dt=dset.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
dadapter.Dispose();
dadapter = null;
myConnectionString.Close();
return dt;

}


protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{

    GridViewBind();
    GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}



protected void ddlPages_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvrPager = GridView1.BottomPagerRow;
    DropDownList ddlPages = (DropDownList)gvrPager.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlPages");

    GridViewBind();
    GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
    GridView1.PageIndex = ddlPages.SelectedIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}


protected void Paginate(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int intCurIndex = GridView1.PageIndex;

    switch (e.CommandArgument.ToString().ToLower())
    {
        case "First":
            GridView1.PageIndex = 0;
            break;
        case "Prev":
            GridView1.PageIndex = intCurIndex - 1;
            break;
        case "Next":
            GridView1.PageIndex = intCurIndex + 1;
            break;
        case "Last":
            GridView1.PageIndex = GridView1.PageCount - 1;
            break;
    }

    GridView1.DataBind();
}


protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)(e.Row.FindControl("ddlpages"));
        Label lblPageCount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblPageCount");

        if (lblPageCount != null)
            lblPageCount.Text = GridView1.PageCount.ToString();

        for (int i = 1; i <= GridView1.PageCount; i++)
        {
            ddl.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        ddl.SelectedIndex = GridView1.PageIndex;

        if (GridView1.PageIndex == 0)
        {
            ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton1")).Visible = false;
            ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton2")).Visible = false;
        }

        if (GridView1.PageIndex + 1 == GridView1.PageCount)
        {
            ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton3")).Visible = false;
            ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton4")).Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    sortingDirection = string.Empty;
    if (dir == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Descending;
        sortingDirection = "Desc";
    }
    else
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Ascending;
        sortingDirection = "Asc";
    }

    DataView sortedView = new DataView(GridViewBind());
    sortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + sortingDirection; 
    PleaseWait();
    GridViewBind();
    GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
public SortDirection dir
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["dirState"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["dirState"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
        }
        return (SortDirection)ViewState["dirState"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["dirState"] = value;
    }
}

    public string SortField
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)ViewState["SortField"] ?? "empid"; // default sort 
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["SortField"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void gridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        sortingDirection = string.Empty;
        if (dir == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            dir = SortDirection.Descending;
            sortingDirection = "Desc";
        }
        else
        {
            dir = SortDirection.Ascending;
            sortingDirection = "Asc";
        }

        DataView sortedView = new DataView(GridViewBind());
        sortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + sortingDirection;
        SortField = e.SortExpression;
        PleaseWait();
        GridView1.DataSource = sortedView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }


public DataTable GridViewBind()
{

sql1 = " SELECT * FROM `tbl` ORDER BY empid DESC; ";

dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql1, myConnectionString);
dset = new DataSet();
dset.Clear();
dadapter.Fill(dset);
DataTable dt=dset.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
dadapter.Dispose();
dadapter = null;
myConnectionString.Close();
return dt;

}


    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        sortingDirection = string.Empty;
        if (dir == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            dir = SortDirection.Descending;
            sortingDirection = "Desc";
        }
        else
        {
            dir = SortDirection.Ascending;
            sortingDirection = "Asc";
        }

        DataView sortedView = new DataView(GridViewBind());
        sortedView.Sort = SortField + " " + sortingDirection; 
        PleaseWait();
        GridViewBind();
        GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }


protected void ddlPages_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvrPager = GridView1.BottomPagerRow;
    DropDownList ddlPages = (DropDownList)gvrPager.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlPages");

    GridViewBind();
    GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
    GridView1.PageIndex = ddlPages.SelectedIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}


protected void Paginate(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int intCurIndex = GridView1.PageIndex;

    switch (e.CommandArgument.ToString().ToLower())
    {
        case "First":
            GridView1.PageIndex = 0;
            break;
        case "Prev":
            GridView1.PageIndex = intCurIndex - 1;
            break;
        case "Next":
            GridView1.PageIndex = intCurIndex + 1;
            break;
        case "Last":
            GridView1.PageIndex = GridView1.PageCount - 1;
            break;
    }

    GridView1.DataBind();
}


protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)(e.Row.FindControl("ddlpages"));
        Label lblPageCount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblPageCount");

        if (lblPageCount != null)
            lblPageCount.Text = GridView1.PageCount.ToString();

        for (int i = 1; i <= GridView1.PageCount; i++)
        {
            ddl.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        ddl.SelectedIndex = GridView1.PageIndex;

        if (GridView1.PageIndex == 0)
        {
            ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton1")).Visible = false;
            ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton2")).Visible = false;
        }

        if (GridView1.PageIndex + 1 == GridView1.PageCount)
        {
            ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton3")).Visible = false;
            ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton4")).Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3**

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    sortingDirection = string.Empty;
    if (dir == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Descending;
        sortingDirection = "Desc";
    }
    else
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Ascending;
        sortingDirection = "Asc";
    }

    DataView sortedView = new DataView(GridViewBind());
    sortedView.Sort = SortField + " " + sortingDirection; 
    PleaseWait();
    GridViewBind();
    GridView1.DataSource = sortedView;
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: isn't it because When you change pages you are just calling GridViewBind() which when data bound there is not sorting expressions being set like you have done in gridView_Sorting

Comment: thanks for help I've edit my first post with new version of **GridView1_PageIndexChanging** but I've error: **Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'SortExpression'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When GridView1_PageIndexChanging() is executing you do not sort the data. To fix it, you need to add to that method same code as in gridView_Sorting() but let GridView1.PageIndex

Update:

To remember the sort field add a new property

```
public string SortField 
{
   get {
      return (string)ViewState["SortField"] ?? "empid"; // default sort 
   }
   set {
      ViewState["SortField"]=value;
   }
}
```

Set it in the sorting event gridView_Sorting() as

```
SortField = e.SortExpression;
```

Now, use it everywhere where you need to get the sort column, e.g. in GridView1_PageIndexChanging()

```
//sortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + sortingDirection; 
sortedView.Sort = SortField + " " + sortingDirection;
```

Update 2:

There are 2 more problems in EDIT3 in the GridView1_PageIndexChanging Method

1. you bind to a wrong data source
2. you change sorting order to an opposite direction

Must be

```
//sortingDirection = string.Empty;
if (dir == SortDirection.Ascending)
{
    //dir = SortDirection.Descending;
    sortingDirection = "Asc"; // "Desc";
}
else
{
    //dir = SortDirection.Ascending;
    sortingDirection = "Desc"; // "Asc";
}

...
GridView1.DataSource = sortedView; //dset.Tables[0];
```

That's should help but in general you code is very insufficient and you might need to look for best practice examples in the internet.

Comment: thanks for help I've edit my first post with new version of **GridView1_PageIndexChanging** but I've error: **Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'SortExpression'**

Comment: Thank you. In EDIT 2 the new version fo my code, I don't have error but change page and missing the sort.

Comment: In the GridView1_PageIndexChanging() you sort a DataView (sortedView) but bind the grid to a different source (dset.Tables[0]). It should be GridView1.DataSource = sortedView;

Comment: thank you, I've replaced in the GridView1_PageIndexChanging() the **GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];** with **GridView1.DataSource = sortedView;** but change page and sort is missing ...

Comment: why do you call GridViewBind() in the GridView1_PageIndexChanging()?

Comment: Even in EDIT3 you call GridViewBind(); - what for? You need to delete it.

Comment: Deleted in **GridView1_PageIndexChanging()** the **GridViewBind();**  change page and sort is missing ...

Comment: you change sorting order to an opposite direction - see updated answer